Spring Data Neo4j Graphql Integration: query with depth > 1 not working
I can not get SDN working with Graphql repositories. If there is a Node hierachy with depth > 1 the respective entities are not queried correctly as demonstrated here: https://github.com/NilsWild/spring-issue-demo/tree/9fb691716d3adfb51b6d7d583d32a6a829de1bfc
What am I missing?
I use a Neo4jRepository that is annotated with @GraphQlRepository. However anything deeper in the graph than depth 1 is returned as null. If the Entity itself is returned through a custom @QueryMapping method it works but that solution queries a lot more than what might be needed (potentially the whole graph).
